# applying dynamic class to <td> based on condition

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to apply css class to "td" based on condition? Please check the below code. I have a table called "FunctionArea" in which I need to create td's dynamically and apply CSS based on condition

```js
var tbody = $('#FunctionArea tbody');
var FArea = ['test','test1','test2','test3'];
$.each(FArea, function (i, FArea) {
  var tr = $('<tr>')
  $('<td>').html(FArea).appendTo(tr);
  $.each(FunctionArea, function (i, FunctionArea) {
    if (FArea == FunctionArea.split(':')[0])
    {
      var tdclass = FunctionArea.split(':')[3] == "Input" ? 'input' : 'delivarable';
      $('<td>').addClass(tdclass);            
      $('<td>').html("<a class='hiddenTab' href=" + FunctionArea.split(':')[2] + ">" + FunctionArea.split(':')[1] + "</a>").appendTo(tr);
    }
  });
  tbody.append(tr);
});
```

```css
table#FunctionArea {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 15px;
  color: #4a4a4d;
  font: 14px/1.4 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
 }
#FunctionArea th,
table.input td {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 13px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 3px 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;*/
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
table.delivarable td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head></head>
<body>    
<table id="FunctionArea">
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the the` jquery` library loaded in your page?

Comment: Yes, i have added only the snippet.

Comment: Wher is `FArea` coming from? And do you have also an `html` page?

Comment: FArea and FunctionArea are two arrays where i store values

Comment: where is your FArea,FunctionArea

Comment: Please let me know how to set tdclass dynamically, FArea is only an array

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] We have no idea what your data `FunctionArea` looks like or what is or isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest avoid direct dom manipulation using "$().html()".
because do not creates usefull object. 
instead create object and append.

`

```
<table id="myTable">
</table>
<button id="btAppend">Append</button>
<style>
    .blue{ color:blue;}
    .red{ color:red;}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var counter=0;
    var myTable=$("#myTable");
    var btAppend=$("#btAppend");

    btAppend.click(function(){
        counter++;

        var tr=$('<tr id="id-mytr-'+counter+'">');
        var td1=$('<td>');
        var tdclass=(counter % 2 == 1)?"blue":"red";
        td1.addClass(tdclass);
        td1.append("Hello");

        tr.append(td1);
        myTable.append(tr);
    });
</script>
```

`

Comment: Giving individual 'Id's to TD's has helped me to solve the issue thanks Rubens for your help and all other who gave me inputs, appreciate your help.